# SSIS File System Task after SQL task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I have one Execute SQL Task (DOE Params) with  script:

```
select 
    SystemCode
    ,[Group]
    ,Process
    ,InputFolder
    ,InputFileName
    ,TargetFileName
from rpt.v_cfg_Report_DOE_Parameters 
where 
Report_Id = ? 
and Procedure_Id = ?
```

And after there is new sql task (RUN DOE CALLER) which taking results from previous query, call procedure, which continue to process data for some another steps. I need to make File System Task which will copy that params from (GET DOE Params) to file and to save that file in folder where I can see which parameters are forwarded to procedure in a purpose of check.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result set from that query to an object variable.  Then use a for each loop container set to ado.net iterator.  This allows you to set the parameters to package variables for each time through.  Those then drive the file system task.  You could also use that query in a source component rather than a sql task.  In the data flow you choose a recordset destination that points to the object variable.